# Simple JQuery AJax Example: Variables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables

I took code from the W3 Schools regard jquery ajax and modified it slightly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load("test/test.php");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<? $a=5; $b=5; $a + $b = $c;?>
<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text???</h2></div>
<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

On my test.php I have this little line:

```
<h2>The answer is: <?=$c?></h2>
```

When I click the button though I am not getting anything, just "The answer is:"

I know this is stupid simple, but I a newb to Jquery AJAX and can't find a solution that answer this question. This is more for my understanding that a real project-based problem.

Thankss

Comment: you never defined `$c` in `test.php`... `test.php` can't access vars in `index.php`  unless you specifically include it into `test.php` (which you don't want to do in this case).

Comment: @KevinB so what would I do to get that kind of effect? Where I have variables above... would have to create a new file where the logic is handled and then include it test.php?

Comment: You would just move `<? $a=5; $b=5; $a + $b = $c;?>` to test.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed above, you cannot access the local variables of one page in test.php using jquery load method. If you want to pass the value of $c variable to test.php, you can achieve by passing it as get variable or using ajax.

Please look at the following example:

## Your Client side file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">        </script>
<?php 
$a=5;
$b=5; 
$c = $a + $b;
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load("test.php?c=<?php echo $c; ?>");
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text???</h2></div>
<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

## And Your Server side file:

```
<h2>The answer is: <?php echo $_GET['c']; ?></h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement you can use any of the three methods:

**get, post or ajax**

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    function readyFunction() {
        $('#result').html("All iss well..");
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax_response.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {id: '12345', 'name': 'AJAX'},
            cache: true
        }).done(function(data){
            data = $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log("I am in done..." + data.id);
        }).success(function(data){
            console.log("I am in success..." + data);
        }).fail(function(data){
            console.log("I am in fail..." + data);
        }).always(function(data){
            console.log("I am in always..." + data);
        });

        $.post({
            url: "ajax_response.php",
            data: {id: '12345', 'name': 'POST'},
            cache: true
        }).done(function(data){
            data = $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log("I am in done..." + data.id);
        }).success(function(data){
            console.log("I am in success..." + data);
        }).fail(function(data){
            console.log("I am in fail..." + data);
        }).always(function(data){
            console.log("I am in always..." + data);
        });

        $.get({
            url: "ajax_response.php",
            data: {id: '12345', 'name': 'GET'},
            method: "POST",
            cache: true
        }).done(function(data){
            data = $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log("I am in done..." + data.id);
        }).success(function(data){
            console.log("I am in success..." + data);
        }).fail(function(data){
            console.log("I am in fail..." + data);
        }).always(function(data){
            console.log("I am in always..." + data);
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(readyFunction);

</script>
```

ajax_response.php

```
<?php
    echo json_encode($_REQUEST);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You specify code is php via these tags

```
<?php some code here ?>
```

Furthermore you are going to want to echo out the value.

```
<h2>The answer is: <?php echo $c ?></h2>
```

This obviously also applies to the assignment of the a,b, and c variables. Also, you assign variables in php left to right as in:

```
$c = $a + $b;
```

Comment: Nope... still doesn't work. Still get "The answer is: "[blank]. Any other suggestions? you can view it live: http://crinno.com/test/